# Why is there "pool pool-1-thread-1" exception in Thread

Tags: java, jdbc

The following code:

```
ExecutorService executor = newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
                    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM function()");
                    boolean result= (boolean) query.uniqueResult();
                }
            }
```

I get an exception :

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at personDao$1.run(PersonDao.java:1080)
```

So it says on the line where `boolean result= (boolean) query.getUniqueResult();`, there is an pool 1 thread 1, why is this happening?

Comment: Is there an exception or isn't there one? Try assigning the result of `uniqueResult` to a variable of type `Object` and checking its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `"pool-1-thread-1"` is coming from the `ExecutorService`.

If your information that the NPE happens in the line

```
boolean resul t = (boolean) query.getUniqueResult();
```

is true, it could be one of the following two causes:

- `query` is `null`.
- `query.getUniqueResult()` returns `null`, and `(boolean) (Boolean) null throws NullPointerException`.

Comment: Edited, my mistake, there is no NPE there.